# Limitar a quantidade de paginas na paginação

Tags: php, paginação

Tenho uma paginação que exibe muitas páginas.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber como posso limitar esse resultado.
Por exemplo se o usuario estiver na página `[5]` , gostaria que aparecesse `[3][4] 5 [6][7]` sempre dois links antes e após a pagina que ele estiver

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    require '../conectaBanco.php';

    //Verificar se esta sendo passado na URL a pagina atual, senao  atribuida a pagina 
    $pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;

    //Selecionar todos os produtos da tabela
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos";
    $query = mysqli_query($conecta, $sql);

    //Contar o total de produtos
    $total_linhas = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    //Seta a quantidade de produtos por pagina
    $quantidade_pg = 1;

    //calcular o numero de pagina necessarias para apresentar os produtos
    $num_pagina = ceil($total_linhas / $quantidade_pg);

    //Calcular o inicio da visualizacao
    $incio = ($quantidade_pg * $pagina) - $quantidade_pg;

    //Selecionar os produtos a serem apresentado na pagina
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos limit $incio, $quantidade_pg";
    $query = mysqli_query($conecta, $sql);
    $total_linhas = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    ?>
```

Exibe a paginação

```
            <?php
            //Verificar a pagina anterior e posterior
            $pagina_anterior = $pagina - 1;
            $pagina_posterior = $pagina + 1;
            ?>
            <div id="bottom" class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <nav class="text-center">
                        <ul class="pagination">
                            <li>
                                <?php if ($pagina_anterior != 0) { ?>
                                    <a href="produtos.php?pagina=<?php echo $pagina_anterior; ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                                    </a>
                                <?php } else { ?>
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </li>
                            <?php
                            //Apresentar a paginacao
                            for ($i = 1; $i < $num_pagina + 1; $i++) {
                                ?>
                                <li><a href="produtos.php?pagina=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <li>
                                <?php if ($pagina_posterior <= $num_pagina) { ?>
                                    <a href="produtos.php?pagina=<?php echo $pagina_posterior; ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                                    </a>
                                <?php } else { ?>
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Não estou respondendo sua pergunta,  apenas dando uma dica com base em experiência própria.  Vc está utilizando select * from produtos na query de contagem.  Se a tabela for pequena e com poucas colunas não tem problema mas em tabelas grandes prefira usar um select count(id)  from produtos onde id é o nome da coluna q é chave primária. Isso devolve um resultset q vc pega usando $linha=mysql_fetch_assoc( $rs) e depois $linha['count']. Ou para usar do jeito que está usando agora,  select id from produtos funciona da mesma maneira com o mysqli_num_rows,  só que sem pegar todas as colunas.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica AntonioAlexandre.